# Asynchronous methods calls with Ruby like with Ajax

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, io, xmpp, blocking

I am working with XMPP and I have a message callback which is activated on the event of every message being sent. My aim is to send the data arriving by the message to an API within the callback and based on the response send something back using the XMPP client.

1. User type message (Browser Chat Client)
2. Message arrives to the server via XMPP
3. Message is sent to the API
4. Response is received
5. Response is sent back to the chat client.

My code for this is as follows

```
admin_muc_client.activate_message_callbacks do |m|            
  sender    = m.from.resource
  room_slug = m.from.node
  message   = m.body                  

  r = HTTParty.get('http://example.com/api/v1/query?msg=message')
  Rails.logger.debug(r.inspect)
  admin_muc_client.send_message("Message #{r.body}") if m.from.resource != 'admin'
end
```

My concern here is that since the callback is evented and the request to the API would be a blocking call this could become a bottleneck for the entire application. 
I would prefer to use something like AJAX for Javascript which would fire the request and when the response is available send data. How could I implement that in Ruby?

I have looked at delayed_job and backgroundrb which look like tools for fire and forget operations. I would need something that activates a callback in an asynchronous manner with the response.

I would really really appreciate some help on how to achieve the asynchronous behavior that i want. I am also familiar with message queues like RabbitMQ which I feel would be addition of significant complexity.

Answer (score 5):

Did you look at [girl_friday](https://github.com/mperham/girl_friday)? From it's wiki -

> girl_friday is a Ruby library for performing asynchronous tasks. Often times you don't want to block a web response by performing some task, like sending an email, so you can just use this gem to perform it in the background. It works with any Ruby application, including Rails 3 applications.
>
> Why not use any of the zillions of other async solutions (Resque, dj, etc)? Because girl_friday is easier and more efficient than those solutions: girl_friday runs in your Rails process and uses the actor pattern for safe concurrency. Because it runs in the same process, you don't have to monitor a separate set of processes, deploy a separate codebase, waste hundreds of extra MB in RAM for those processes, etc. See my intro to Actors in Ruby for more detail.
>
> You do need to write thread-safe code. This is not hard to do: the actor pattern means that you get a message and process that message. There is no shared data which requires locks and could lead to deadlock in your application code. Because girl_friday does use Threads under the covers, you need to ensure that your Ruby environment can execute Threads efficiently. JRuby, Rubinius 1.2 and Ruby 1.9.2 should be sufficient for most applications. I do not support Ruby 1.8 because of its poor threading support.

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome will give this a shot. Maybe this is it.

Comment: What i find is this works in the console but does not add the task to the queue when run in the application in development mode. BTW I'm running passenger and apache in dev mode.